# Algebraic de Rham cohomology vs. analytic de Rham cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, gaga

Let $X$ be a nice variety over $\mathbb{C}$, where nice probably means smooth and proper.

I want to know: How can we show that the hypercohomology of the algebraic de Rham complex agrees with the hypercohomology of the analytic de Rham complex (equivalently the cohomology of the constant sheaf $\mathbb{C}$ in the analytic topology)? Does this follow immediately from GAGA? If not, how do you prove it?

I think that this does not follow immediately from GAGA because, while the sheaves $\Omega_X^i$ are coherent, the de Rham $d$ is not a map of coherent sheaves (it is not multiplicative). Am I correct in my thinking?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think you can get this directly from GAGA. The reference that I know for this result is Grothendieck, [On the de Rham cohomology of algebraic varieties](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=199194). It is short, beautiful, and in English.

Comment: As many people are pointing out below, you can get this from GAGA for proper varieties, and certainly Grothendieck's proof uses GAGA among other tools (see footnote 6).

Answer (score 15):

If $X$ is smooth and proper, GAGA does in fact suffice (despite the observation that $d$ is not $\mathcal{O}_X$-linear:  One obtains a comparison map of hypercohomology spectral sequences; it is an isomorphism on the $E_2$ page by GAGA, and thus on the $E_\infty$ page.

It is to prove the general case (i.e., $X$ smooth but not necessarily proper) that one needs to do additional work.

Comment: Some care is needed in the application of GAGA even in the proper case since the lack of $\mathcal{O}$-linearity for the maps in the deRham complex implies that one needs to be attentive to how a comparison morphism is actually defined and why it is an isomorphism. None of this requires anything deep, but for a rigorous argument one cannot just blindly "plug it into" some general nonsense about analytification of complexes of sheaves of modules.

Comment: That's a great point --- the existence of the comparison morphism isn't formal! This is made clear by noting that there's no formal construction where one "plugs in" the algebraic deRham complex and gets out the analytic deRham complex; at some point you need to know how to differentiate holomorphic functions not coming from algebra.  So yes, to define the comparison map we need to verify that the level-wise "analytification" maps are compatible with the differentials (i.e., that you can differentiate an algebraic form by treating it as a holomorphic form).

Comment: Brian -- the key observation is that whenever we have a ringed space $(X,O)$ and a sheaf $F$ of $O$-modules, then when computing the cohomology it doens't matter whether we consider $F$ as a sheaf of $O$-modules or just as a sheaf of abelian groups. So the analytic to algebraic comparison morphism exists for general reasons: just consider the algebraic and analytic de Rham complexes as complexes of sheaves of abelian groups on different sites, analytic and Zariski. It is a quasi-isomorphism for any $\Omega^i$ by GAGA, hence a quasi-isomorphism.

Comment: Algori: I'm afraid what you write is not precisely correct. Firstly, you have to pull back the algebraic complex from the Zariski topology to the analytic one to get a comparison map for `general reasons.' Next, the maps of sheaves is definitely *not* a quasi-isomorphism. If you'd like a quasi-isomorphism, the easiest thing is perhaps to build up a map between two Cech complexes in the obvious manner, using affine open coverings (it works for the cohomology of the analytic sheaves because these are Stein manifolds). It's rather important to remember that GAGA theorems are all *global*.

Comment: Algori, I hope Minhyong's comments help to clarify to you what the point of my comment was (which seems to have been missed in your comment).  Let me try again: the general nonsense of analytification of sheaves of modules doesn't literally include the d-maps in the deRham complexes, due to their non-linearity, so one has to make (admittedly easy, but still necessary!) arguments specific to that situation to set up the relation between the two complexes before putting it into the spectral sequence for underlying complexes of abelian sheaves).

Comment: Minhoyng, I was talking precisely of the pullback from analytic to Zariski sites. This induces an isomorphism $H^*(X^{Zar},\Omega^i)\to H^*(X^{an},Omega^i)$ (hence my use of the term "quasi-isomorphism", which may have been misleading); of course, $\Omega^i$ on the right and on the left stands for sheaves wrt different topologies. So the (hyper)cohomology map $H^*(X^{Zar},\Omega^*)\to H^*(Z^{an},\Omega^*)$ is an iso by comparing the spectral sequences. Notice that this comparison map is induced by adjunction and the map of complexes of sheaves of abelian groups on $X^{an}$.

Comment: Brian -- I'm unable to give a precise meaning to your remark that " the general nonsense of analytification of sheaves of modules doesn't literally include the d-maps in the deRham complexes,"

Comment: Algori, this might help: Let `$f: X_{an} \to X_{zar}$` be the natural map of locally ringed sites, `$f^{-1}$` the pullback on *sheaves of groups*, and `$f^*$` the pullback on *sheaves of modules*.  Then, GAGA is relating the cohomology of $\mathcal{F}$ on `$X_{zar}$` with the cohomology of `$f^* \mathcal{F}$` (not `$f^{-1} \mathcal{F}$`) on `$X_{an}$`. Then $f^{-1} \Omega_{zar}^*$ has a differential, but we need to *provide* the analytic deRham differential and a map of complexes `$f^{-1} \Omega_{zar}^* \to \Omega_{an}^*$` that is identified with the natural map `$f^{-1} \to f^*$` levelwise.

Answer (score 9):

Various people have answered the question, and also brought up some of the subtleties in applying GAGA. So I won't  rehash all that. So let me just suggest the additional reference:

Deligne, Équations différentielles à points singuliers réguliers

especially Chapter II, section 6. These issues are dealt with carefully in a more
general setting of de Rham cohomology with coefficients in a regular integrable connection.
The result is no doubt true for a regular holonomic D-module, and it would be nice if
someone wrote this down carefully. But perhaps I'm straying too far from the original topic.

Answer (score 7):

This does follow from GAGA via the spectral sequences associated to the dumb filtrations on the algebraic and analytic de Rham complexes of sheaves, see p. 96 of [tome 29](http://archive.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1966__29__95_0) of PMIHES in a paper of Grothendieck (1966).

Comment: Slightly unrelated comment: When you cite a paper like this, it's probably better to link to the page rather than the pdf (when possible) like I did in the edited link.  I know that's what the staff has suggested at least for the arXiv.

Comment: FWIW (my understanding of) the underlying reason for this logic is that arXiv sometimes generates pdfs on the fly and dumps them in a temporary directory and offers you a link to that. So linking "directly to the pdf" equals linking to a temp file that in a few months' time will be gone. Who knows if Numdam does the same---but who cares, because whether they do or they don't, linking to the journal page will surely always work.

Comment: As far as I know, Numdam gives permanent URLs for djvu, pdf etc files. It is safe to directly link to pdf files in numdam.
